# How to put frontend of my site in maintenance mode

Tags: maintenance

I need to put frontend of my site to maintenance mode. so I enabled maintenance flag by creating empty folder in the name maintenance.flag in the root folder. But when I do this, my backend panel is also getting locked under maintenance mode. I want to work in my back panel So someone kindly guide me to enable maintenance mode only at frontend.

Comment: Refer https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/maintenance-mode.htm

Answer (score 2):

To do this, open the **index.php** in root and add (remembering to edit the `‘allowed’` array to contain the IP’s you want to be able to access the site);

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$allowed = array('1.1.1.1','2.2.2.2'); // these are the IP's that are allowed to view the site.
```

Next, search for this piece of code

```
if (file_exists($maintenanceFile)) {
```

and replace it with this:

```
 if (file_exists($maintenanceFile) && !in_array($ip, $allowed)) {
```

Simple. Now you can access the site (admin + front end), while others see its maintenance mode.

Source: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/maintenance-mode-in-magento/

Hope this make sense to you

Comment: Should I add my system public IP over there?

Comment: Yes. Or just search in google `what is my IP?`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, We have to add

`$url=(!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

before

```
$maintenanceFile = 'maintenance.flag';
```

in index.php